# type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error

Tags: sql, subquery, amazon-redshift

I ran into this error:

> "This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to
>   internal error"

when executing the following query on Matillion ( an ETL tool for Redshift).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  "sap"."tracking_no" AS "tracking_no",
  (select case when len("sap"."order_create_time")=6 and
                 regexp_instr("sap"."order_create_date",'[a-zA-Z]')=0 and 
                 regexp_instr("sap"."order_create_time",'[a-zA-Z]')=0
            then CAST(CONCAT(CONCAT(cast(isnull("sap"."order_create_date",'1900-01-01') as VARCHAR(10)), ' '),
                   CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."order_create_time",'000000'), 1,2), ':'),
                   SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."order_create_time",'000000'), 3,2)),':'),
                   SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."order_create_time",'000000'), 5,2))) as timestamp)
            when len("sap"."order_create_time")=5 and regexp_instr("sap"."order_create_date",'[a-zA-Z]')=0 and 
                 regexp_instr("sap"."order_create_time",'[a-zA-Z]')=0
            then  CAST(CONCAT(CONCAT(cast(isnull("sap"."order_create_date",'1900-01-01') as VARCHAR(10)), ' '),
                       CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(concat('0',SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."order_create_time",'000000'), 5,1)), ':'),
                       SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."order_create_time",'000000'), 3,2)),':'),
                       SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."order_create_time",'000000'), 5,1))) as timestamp)
            else cast('1900-01-01 000000' as timestamp)
   end)  as "order_date_time",
   (select case when len("sap"."ship_time")=6 and
                 regexp_instr("sap"."ship_date",'[a-zA-Z]')=0 and 
                 regexp_instr("sap"."ship_time",'[a-zA-Z]')=0
            then CAST(CONCAT(CONCAT(cast(isnull("sap"."ship_date",'1900-01-01') as VARCHAR(10)), ' '),
                   CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."ship_time",'000000'), 1,2), ':'),
                   SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."ship_time",'000000'), 3,2)),':'),
                   SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."ship_time",'000000'), 5,2))) as timestamp)
            when len("sap"."ship_time")=5 and regexp_instr("sap"."ship_date",'[a-zA-Z]')=0 and 
                 regexp_instr("sap"."ship_time",'[a-zA-Z]')=0
            then  CAST(CONCAT(CONCAT(cast(isnull("sap"."ship_date",'1900-01-01') as VARCHAR(10)), ' '),
                       CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(concat('0',SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."ship_time",'000000'), 5,1)), ':'),
                       SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."ship_time",'000000'), 3,2)),':'),
                       SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."ship_time",'000000'), 5,1))) as timestamp)
            else cast('1900-01-01 000000' as timestamp)
end)  as "ship_date_time",
  "fedex"."TRACKING_NUMBER" AS "TRACKING_NUMBER"      
FROM fed_ex_feed AS "fedex"
     LEFT OUTER JOIN     
     sap_delivery AS "sap" 
     ON "fedex"."TRACKING_NUMBER" = "sap"."tracking_no"
WHERE sap.order_create_date is not null and
      fedex.DELIVERY_DATE is not null
```

I tried searching for resolutions, but couldn't find any resolutions on the internet.

Is it something to do with the redshift cluster as it suggests as an internal error?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hereby posting the updated query which works now. Remove the `select` statements in front of the `case` and it works.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  "sap"."tracking_no" AS "tracking_no",
   case when len("sap"."order_create_time")=6 and
                 regexp_instr("sap"."order_create_date",'[a-zA-Z]')=0 and 
                 regexp_instr("sap"."order_create_time",'[a-zA-Z]')=0
            then CAST(CONCAT(CONCAT(cast(isnull("sap"."order_create_date",'1900-01-01') as VARCHAR(10)), ' '),
                   CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."order_create_time",'000000'), 1,2), ':'),
                   SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."order_create_time",'000000'), 3,2)),':'),
                   SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."order_create_time",'000000'), 5,2))) as timestamp)
            when len("sap"."order_create_time")=5 and regexp_instr("sap"."order_create_date",'[a-zA-Z]')=0 and 
                 regexp_instr("sap"."order_create_time",'[a-zA-Z]')=0
            then  CAST(CONCAT(CONCAT(cast(isnull("sap"."order_create_date",'1900-01-01') as VARCHAR(10)), ' '),
                       CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(concat('0',SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."order_create_time",'000000'), 5,1)), ':'),
                       SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."order_create_time",'000000'), 3,2)),':'),
                       SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."order_create_time",'000000'), 5,1))) as timestamp)
            else cast('1900-01-01 000000' as timestamp)
   end  as "order_date_time"
   , case when len("sap"."ship_time")=6 and
                 regexp_instr("sap"."ship_date",'[a-zA-Z]')=0 and 
                 regexp_instr("sap"."ship_time",'[a-zA-Z]')=0
            then CAST(CONCAT(CONCAT(cast(isnull("sap"."ship_date",'1900-01-01') as VARCHAR(10)), ' '),
                   CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."ship_time",'000000'), 1,2), ':'),
                   SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."ship_time",'000000'), 3,2)),':'),
                   SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."ship_time",'000000'), 5,2))) as timestamp)
            when len("sap"."ship_time")=5 and regexp_instr("sap"."ship_date",'[a-zA-Z]')=0 and 
                 regexp_instr("sap"."ship_time",'[a-zA-Z]')=0
            then  CAST(CONCAT(CONCAT(cast(isnull("sap"."ship_date",'1900-01-01') as VARCHAR(10)), ' '),
                       CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(concat('0',SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."ship_time",'000000'), 5,1)), ':'),
                       SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."ship_time",'000000'), 3,2)),':'),
                       SUBSTRING(isnull("sap"."ship_time",'000000'), 5,1))) as timestamp)
            else cast('1900-01-01 000000' as timestamp)
end  as "ship_date_time",
  "fedex"."TRACKING_NUMBER" AS "TRACKING_NUMBER"      
FROM fed_ex_feed AS "fedex"
     LEFT OUTER JOIN     
     sap_delivery AS "sap" 
     ON "fedex"."TRACKING_NUMBER" = "sap"."tracking_no"
WHERE sap.order_create_date is not null and
      fedex.DELIVERY_DATE is not null
```